# Oracle - Bring Back previous Row based on Value and Next row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a slight problem that i have been trying to sort out...

The Database shows records of unavailability for a particular Cell.. if the Cell is up it records 0 as unavailability and when the cell is down it shows as 3600 (secs). when a record has 3600 in one of the fields then a 1 is placed in another field to show it as a Cell Out of Service (COOS).

I have been able to search records to show all current COOS but what i need to be able to do is search and show when a cell went down and when it came back up...

so i need to search the Database for first instance of '3600' then bring back the previous record that shows '0' and then also bring back the next record that shows '0' again this will then tell me the dates / Times that cell went down.

This is an example of the Data:

[image]

I would need the Query to bring bring back this:

[image]

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Thank you jarlh, i wasnt sure how to add the images like that!

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d24e/11)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( Cell, Date_Time, COOS, Unavailability ) AS
          SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '10' HOUR, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '9' HOUR, 0, 3600 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '8' HOUR, 0, 3600 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '7' HOUR, 0, 3600 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '6' HOUR, 0, 3600 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '5' HOUR, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '4' HOUR, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'D02463', DATE '2015-11-16' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Cell,
       Cell_Down,
       Cell_Up,
       (Cell_Up - Cell_Down)*24 AS Time_Down
FROM   (
  SELECT Cell,
         Date_Time AS Cell_Up,
         LAG( Date_Time ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Cell ORDER BY Date_Time ) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR AS Cell_Down
  FROM   Data
  WHERE  COOS = 1
)
WHERE Cell_Down < Cell_Up
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d24e/11/0)**:

```
|   CELL |                  CELL_DOWN |                    CELL_UP | TIME_DOWN |
|--------|----------------------------|----------------------------|-----------|
| D02463 | November, 16 2015 06:00:00 | November, 16 2015 10:00:00 |         4 |
```